# How to check the value of button accept or reject which is comes from database and in the reslt user click on it and accept it -- obj c

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to check the value of button accept or reject which is comes from database and in the reslt user click on it and accept it and the accept value is save in the database.

There is two button one for accept the request and other for reject the request. I show you the accept request button code,where I write the condition if the status of the request is pending or rejected so the user is able to click on it and in return button text is convert into accepted text.

Here is the condition of accept button. If I click on it so it check the value of pending and rejected and give the result of accept text in the button.

The button code is:

```
- (IBAction)btn_Accept:(UIButton *)sender
{
    Request *comingReq = [objectHolderArray objectAtIndex:sender.tag];
    if ([comingReq.status isEqualToString:@"Pending"] || [comingReq.status isEqualToString:@"Rejected" ])
    {
        objectHolderArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        NSString *ID = [prefs stringForKey:@"id"];
        NSLog(@"%@" , ID);
        NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@""];
        NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
        NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URL];
    } else if ([comingReq.status  isEqualToString:@"Pending" ]) || ([comingReq.status isEqualToString:@"Accepted" ]) {
        NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@""];
        NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URL];
    }
```

When I passed a .text to hidden_status so there is no error but when I passed the .text to the btn_Accept so it gives an error.what type I used for btn_accept.

Comment: request.request what is this

Comment: in the btn_Accept, 1st request is an object and the 2nd request represent the object value.Like in the hidden_status.Actully the btn_Accept is a button and i want to make it a dynamic button i mean there value is come from data base using web service but .text is not suitable with the _Accept.text.

Comment: Your question is incomprehensible. You need to go back and edit your question to explain what you are trying to do at a high level, not **how** you are trying to do it. It seems like you have some misconceptions.

Comment: You can't seem to explain your goal clearly and coherently so I'm voting to close this question.

Answer (score 0):

Dot notation lets you invoke the getter/setter of an object's property.

The code `cell.hidden_status.text = @"string"` says "fetch the hidden_status property of `cell`. Then set the `text` property of hidden_status to "string".

The compiler will complain if the type of "cell" does not have a property "hidden_status". Likewise it will complain if the type of the cell's hidden_status property does not have a text property.

`UITextField` and `UITextView` objects have `text` properties. `UIButton` objects do not have a `text` property, so you can't use code like

```
button.text = @"string"
```

If you want to set the title of a button there is a special method, `-[setTitle:forSate:]` that lets you set a button's title.

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: but how to pass the string to it ,i mean i want to get dynamic data on the button

Comment: Buttons are view objects. They should not hold data. They should be used to display information to the user, and to collect actions from the user. Why do you want to set data on a button?

Comment: actually i want to make two buttons one for accept and other for reject  and here is the condition but the accept and pending is comes from database;
- (IBAction)btn_Accept:(UIButton *)sender
{
    - (IBAction)btn_Accept:(UIButton *)sender
{
    Request *comingReq = [objectHolderArray objectAtIndex:sender.tag];
    if ([comingReq.status isEqualToString:@"Pending"] || [comingReq.status isEqualToString:@"Rejected" ])
    {
        objectHolderArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        NSString *ID = [prefs stringForKey:@"id"];
       ....
as i methion on the top

Comment: Don't post multiple lines of code in a comment. The lack of formatting makes it unreadable. And what does setting text on buttons have to do with having an accept button and a reject button?

Comment: yes they have an accept and reject text when i click on it.

Comment: That makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: Dear  Duncan C,as i already mention it there is two button one for accept the request and other for reject the request. i show you the accept request button code,where i write the condition if the status of the request is pending and rejected so the user is able to  click on it and in return button text is convert into accepted text. and that's it.